# gb4e center example text

Tags: spacing, linguistics, gb4e

I'm writing an article with several short example sentences. The document as a whole would look better if my example sentences were horizontally centered rather than left-aligned. Of course, I still need the labels on the left. How can I achieve this? Here's a simple MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
  \ex This sentence is short.
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `hfil` like: `\ex \hfil This sentence is short.`

Comment: Works like a charm with Philex and Forest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\hfill` and `\hfill\null`:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
  \ex \hfill This sentence is short.\hfill\null
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\hspace*{\fill}` won't disappear. Using `\null` is not the best option, as it is an undocumented command.