# Centering trees

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-trees, trees, linguistics, linguex

How can I centre a tree, moving it to the middle of the page, whilst keeping `\ex.` in its normal position?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. \begin{tikzpicture}
     \Tree [.VP [.V saw ] [.DP [.N Kim ] ] ]
     \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE doesn't compile without adding `\usepackage{linguex}`. The same was true of [the question you asked yesterday](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258850/42880). Please edit the question to fix this, and try to make sure the MWE compiles **as it is** before submitting the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem here has more to do with how to center a `linguex` example than how to center the tree, so it is actually asking essentially the same thing as [gb4e center example text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/206714/42880), but for `linguex` instead of `gb4e`. The solutions end up being the same:

- Use `\hfil` before and after the `tikzpicture` environment, as suggested by Harish Kumar's comment on the question linked above.
- Use `\hspace*{\fill}` before and after the `tikzpicture` environment, as suggested by egreg's comment to this answer.
- Use `\hfill` before and after the `tikzpicture` environment, as suggested by Peter Grill's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206717/42880) to the question linked above. You just have to make sure there is something with zero width at the end of the example (I used `\hspace{0pt}` below, but you could use `\null` as Peter Grill did); otherwise, the tree will be right-aligned instead of centered.

These yield the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{showframe} % this just shows where the margins are -- comment out for the final version
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}

\ex. \lipsum[121]

\ex. \hfil
     \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline] % baseline makes the example number stay at the top of the tree
     \Tree [.VP [.V saw ] [.DP [.N Kim ] ] ]
     \end{tikzpicture}%
     \hfil

\ex. \hspace*{\fill}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline] % baseline makes the example number stay at the top of the tree
     \Tree [.VP [.V saw ] [.DP [.N Kim ] ] ]
     \end{tikzpicture}%
     \hspace*{\fill}

\ex. \hfill
     \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline] % baseline makes the example number stay at the top of the tree
     \Tree [.VP [.V saw ] [.DP [.N Kim ] ] ]
     \end{tikzpicture}%
     \hfill\hspace{0pt} % without \hspace{0pt}, the tree would be right-aligned

\ex. \lipsum[130]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\hspace*{\fill}` instead.

Comment: `\hspace*{\fill}` adds a zero skip at the end just to avoid the problem you saw with `\hfill`, which is due to the fact that `\par` always issues `\unskip`.