# Aligning gb4e examples with tikz-qtree

Tags: linguistics, tikz-qtree, gb4e

I would like to fit multiple tree structures onto one and the same page (preferably next to each other), while also numbering them with `gb4e` so I can refer to them later on. Although this seems to work, I have a problem with the alignment of the `gb4e` numbers; for some reason they do not align properly.

I have included working code below, together with an example.

I have tried working with `multicols`, inserting different kinds of skips, `hline`, `hfill`, text with `phantom`, but nothing seems to work properly.

Any recommendation whatsoever would be really helpful!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{exe}
\begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
        \ex SVO
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \Tree
                [.AgrSP \node(subj){Subj}; 
                    [.AgrS\1 
                        [.AgrSº \node{AgrSº};\node(verb){Vº}; ]
                        [.VP \node(subjtrace){$<$Subj$>$};
                            [.V\1 \node(verbtrace){$<$Vº$>$}; ]]]]]
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
        \ex VSO
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \Tree
            [.CP
                [.Cº
                    [.Cº ]
                    [.AgrSº \node(agrs){AgrSº};\node(verb){Vº}; ]]      
                [.AgrSP \node(subj){Subj};
                    [.AgrS\1 \node(agrstrace){$<$AgrSº$>$}; 
                        [.VP \node(subjtrace){$<$Subj$>$};
                            [.V\1 \node(verbtrace){$<$Vº$>$}; ]]]]]
            \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
        \ex CSOV
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \Tree
            [.CP
                [.Cº \node{Cº};\node{AgrSº}; ]      
                [.AgrSP \node{Subj}; 
                    [.AgrS\1 \node{<AgrSº>};  
                        [.VP \node{<Subj>}; 
                            [.V\1 \node{Vº}; ]]]]]
            \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}
\end{exe}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I solved it by using `multicols` together with something I found over [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259031/centering-trees) on centering trees with the help `\hfil` and on using `[baseline]` to keep the example numbers above the trees. This made my trees go into the margins, so I provided a `\newline` after each `\ex` and that seemed to solve that issue. I'm sure, however, that this is very rough-and-ready and that there are probably way better ways to solve this, so feel free to comment!

Updated code:

```
\begin{exe}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \ex SVO
        \newline
        \hfil
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \Tree
            [.AgrSP \node(subj){Subj}; 
                [.AgrS\1 
                    [.AgrSº \node{AgrSº};\node(verb){Vº}; ]
                    [.VP \node(subjtrace){$<$Subj$>$};
                        [.V\1 \node(verbtrace){$<$Vº$>$}; ]                         
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            \end{tikzpicture}\hfil}
        \columnbreak
        \ex VSO
        \newline
        \hfil
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \Tree
            [.CP
                [.Cº
                    [.Cº ]
                        [.AgrSº \node(agrs){AgrSº};\node(verb){Vº}; ]
                ]       
                [.AgrSP \node(subj){Subj};
                    [.AgrS\1 \node(agrstrace){$<$AgrSº$>$}; 
                        [.VP \node(subjtrace){$<$Subj$>$};
                            [.V\1 \node(verbtrace){$<$Vº$>$}; ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \hfil}
        \columnbreak
        \ex CSOV
        \newline
        \hfil
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \Tree
            [.CP
                [.Cº \node{Cº};\node{AgrSº}; ]      
                [.AgrSP \node{Subj}; 
                    [.AgrS\1 \node{<AgrSº>};  
                        [.VP \node{<Subj>}; 
                            [.V\1 \node{Vº}; ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \hfil}
    \end{multicols}
\end{exe}
```